# C++ template programming struct vs template

Tags: c++, oop, struct, generic-programming

To provide a functionality for a class cls, say, 'add', following are the types I decided:

```
struct add
{
      add sum(add other) { ... }
};
```

vs.

```
template<typename Add>
Add sum(Add one, Add two) { ... }
```

Which approach should be preferred, what advantages do the first have over the second and vice versa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Which approach should be preferred, what advantages do the first have over the second and vice versa?*

I believe the question does not have a straightforward answer. I think this goes down to the [Generic Vs Object Oriented Programming](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GenericVsObjectOrientedProgramming) battle.

See also [On the Tension Between Object-Oriented and Generic Programming in C++](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/type_erasure.html).

Answer (score 2):

There are two things different between your examples.  Firstly, as you rightly point out, your second example is using a function template.  But secondly, it's using a *free function*, vs. a member-function.

For a fair comparison, you ought to be comparing:

```
add sum(add one, add two) { ... }
```

and:

```
template<typename Add>
Add sum(Add one, Add two) { ... }
```

Whilst the second variation *could* be more useful, it depends on how you're going to write the function body.  Can it be written in a generic way, and still perform operations on `add` objects?

Answer (score 0):

First one doesn't make sense to me, or it is so bad that it shouldn't make sense, because you write a class just to perform some "operation". A class is supposed to represent an object in object-oriented programming (Or if its class template, it can act as meta-function in template meta-programmig).

For operation, functions make sense that operate on object(s). So the second one makes sense, but I would change the *name* of type argument as:

```
template<typename T>
T sum(const T & one, const T & two) { ... }
```

After all, what was `Add`?

Answer (score 0):

When are the type-dependent decisions going to be made? if runtime then you must use virtual methods, if compile time then you can probably use templates instead (of course you can use virtual methods even if the type is fixed at runtime, but this is less efficient).

If the types are fixed at runtime you can use template some tricks to avoid telling which types you're using and having the compiler finding them and generate proper code.

Note however that C++ doesn't allow partial specialization on template functions, only on template classes so for maximum flexibility you may need to wrap your functionalities as methods of template structures (even static methods are ok). Once you have your template class compile-time dispatching machinery in place you can add template functions to allow type deduction and simplify the syntax.